# Error communicating with the remote browser

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

This error happen when i try execute this looping:

```
Robot robox = new Robot();
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

//LINKS
String[] l = new String[3];
l[0] = "http://www.google.com";
l[1] = "http://www.wallmart.com";
l[2] = "http://www.google.com";

for(int i = 0; i < l.length; i++){

    driver.get(l[i]);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();;

    robox.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    robox.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
    robox.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    robox.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
}
```

I have read this may happen because I close the browser, but don't know how solve this.

**ERROR**

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"

 org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the 

remote browser. It may have died.

    Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cb', time: '2013-10-18 17:15:02'

    System info: host: 'My-PC', ip: '10.0.0.50', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', 

os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace, please?

Comment: What error ? Posting the code without the error is like going to hospital and don't say where it hurts.

Comment: error posted, i dont know how get stacktrace...

Answer (score 1):

Just read what you are trying to do in human language:

```
1. Open new Firefox window
2. Type "www.google.com" into Firefox adress bar and press Enter
3. Close Firefox
4. Type "http://www.wallmart.com" into Firefox adress bar and press Enter
```

At step 4 you must say to yourself: "Wait, what? But I did close it!" And thats what I feel the error is about. so to fix it I would propose adding `driver = new FirefoxDriver();` at the end of the loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < l.length; i++){

driver.get(l[i]);
driver.manage().window().maximize();;

robox.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robox.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
robox.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robox.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}
```

anyway, did you know that for closing the window you can also just call `driver.close();` and it will do **exactly** the same as you do by using Robot?